# How to return a 419 HTTP status in a Symfony 2 Response object

Tags: api, rest, symfony

I'm currently working on an HTTP API in Symfony 2 for which I have implemented OAuth2 Password Credentials for authentication. On authentication the client received two tokens, one access and one refresh token.

Somehow I need to be able to inform the client that the access token is no longer valid and that the refresh token must be used to obtain a new access token.

I have gone through the list of HTTP codes [1] and to me the 419 Authentication Timeout status seems the most appropriate. However, when I use this in the `Response` object I actually receive a 500 status instead:

```
return new Response("OK", 419);
```

Results:

```
$ curl -X GET http://local.api

< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Thu, 23 Jan 2014 21:34:39 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Debug-Token: b7c386
< X-Debug-Token-Link: /app_dev.php/_profiler/b7c386
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I get the impression that the `Response` object doesn't seem to support this code (looking through the list of constants defined in the class) but from the `Response` class code itself I can't detect any logic that wouldn't allow me to send a 419.

I'm currently falling back on the 511 Network Authentication Required but I prefer to use the 419 instead. How can I do this?

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: is there a reason you are alerting the user that the token expired?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just refresh the token right away instead of making the user manually click something in order to refresh?  It just seems like a better user experience

Comment: Every authenticated request of the API requires you to send the access token. When the access token is no longer valid the server needs to let the client know about this. The client then needs to send the refresh token to obtain a new access token (and refresh token). This is simply how OAuth2 works. However, the question is in regards to the `Response` object, not the OAuth2 flow...

Comment: Just for grins, try returning a 418 code.  That should tell you that your code is working.  The S2 Response class does not have 419 defined.  A quick glance did not reveal where 419 was being converted to 500.  But if 418 works then at least the problem will have been narrowed down.

Comment: I'm using a 511 which seems a better match..

Comment: Right.  But my point was that if 418 (which is defined) works but 419 doesn't then we know something is going on.  Returning 418 is just a test.

Comment: I know. That's why I'm currently using 511 because I know it works... :)

Comment: Puzzling that you won't test with 418.  Oh well.

Comment: OK. Tested. It works. This is because 418 is listed as a constant in the class definition: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html I.e. the response object only supports codes listed in the class.

Comment: In spite of what @Sehael answered, I don't really see anywhere in the Response object that is checking for invalid 4xx codes.  At least not in S2.3 and S2.4.  Be interesting to put a breakpoint in the sendHeaders method to see if 419 was sent.  It could be that the web server might be making the change.

Comment: Good point. Hadn't thought of that yet...

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [Response constructor](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html#method___construct), it throws an `InvalidArgumentException` exception if the status code is not valid.  You will need to use a different status code (take a look at the class constants for the valid codes in Symfony)

Comment: The thing is that whether the specified code is valid or not is debatable. To me this seems like a bug in the framework because it means that when new codes are introduced they are not valid unless they are added to the framework. I.e. so basically this is not possible with the `Response` object as is.

Comment: @Sehael - Can you post a snippet showing where the 419 code is being checked?

Comment: Good comment actually. I looked for it as well but couldn't directly find it. I either must have missed it or it's checked further down the exception handling chain...

Comment: @Luke The [validation code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L1117) is just file... I think some other part of your application blows up... In the respone headers there is a link where you can check in the symfony profiler what happened `X-Debug-Token-Link: /app_dev.php/_profiler/b7c386`

Comment: I think this actually might be a problem with Apache instead. There is not much of an application, I'm currently testing with the most bare bone out-of-the-box Symfony 2.4 install with a single controller that simply returns a `Response` object with a 419 status code. The debug doesn't tell me much, probably because from Symfony's point of view nothing is actually wrong..

Comment: For testing you can use `php app/console server:run` to see if it works without apache

Comment: The Response class only checks if the code is between 100 and 600. I think also there is a error with the webserver itself, or a error in the code (check the error log). Btw 419 isn't defined in the standard neither by IANA.